# Prove that $T^n$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> Prove or give a counterexample: If $V$ is a complex vector space and $\text{dim V} = n$ and $T \in L(V)$, then $T^n$ is diagonalizable.

In order to show that $T$ is diagonalizable I need to show that I have $n$ distinct eigenvalues.

If I use the theorem that states that if $V$ is a complex vector space and $T \in L(V)$ then there is a basis consisting of the generalized eigenvectors of $T$, then is this sufficient, because I feel like this is more complicated than that? Any tips or help? Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't you need to show you have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, instead of distinct eigenvalues to conclude $T$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: the fact is that $T^n$ can be expressed by a combination of $T, T^2,.. T^{n-1}$ by a theorem of Caley, if i'm not mistaken

Comment: @mwmjp $n$ distinct eigenvalues is a sufficient condition to the existence of $n$ linearly independent vectors (eigenvectors actually) and hence diagonalizability.

Comment: @GitGud But not a necessary condition, so it won't help us if $T$'s eigenvalues aren't distinct (which is perfectly possible).

Comment: Did you try to see what happens in specific examples? Take your favorite non-diagonalizable $2 \times 2$ matrix, is its square diagonalizable?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez Derp, for some reason I was thinking in terms of nilpotence in my deleted answer. Anyway you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @whacka Sufficient condition is what matters.

Comment: @GitGud The implication *distinct eigenvalues* $\Rightarrow$ *diagonalizable* doesn't help if $T^n$ doesn't have distinct eigenvalues. So proving this implication is not enough to solve the original problem.

Comment: But proving it has distinct eigenvalues helps and that's what has been the point since your first comment.

Comment: @GitGud You can't prove $T^n$ has distinct eigenvalues; it doesn't necessarily have them.

Comment: @whacka I know that. I repeat, I was addressing your first comment.

Comment: @GitGud My first comment is correct: if $T$ doesn't have distinct eigenvalues, then the the fact that [distinct eigenvalues is a sufficient condition to conclude diagonalizability] won't help us conclude $T^n$ has distinct eigenvalues. (Note this is what I've been saying in all three of my comments, not just the first.) So contrary to your replies to my comments, sufficiency of distinctness does not matter.

Comment: @whacka Your first comment is a statement in form of a question and that statement is: "You need to show that $T$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors to prove it is diagonalizable, instead of proving that it ($T$) has $n$ distinct eigenvectors". This statement is false. And I don't even know why you're mentioning $T^n$. You didn't mention it in your first comment and the OP didn't either in the relevant part (relevant to this discussion) either.

Comment: @GitGud If one were to happen upon something that has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, that would be enough to show it's diagonalizable. In such a case, one wouldn't need to show it has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors. But OP posed the problem with no such hypothesis on $T$. Yet OP claimed that in order to solve his/her problem, he/she'd need to prove it has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. You cannot show an arbitrary linear map $T$ has distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: @whacka I agree with your last comment, I still claim that the answer to the question in your first comment is no.

Comment: @GitGud None of my comments have a question. Assuming you're referring to the question in mwmjp's comment: he/she was also addressing OP's logic, asking 'wouldn't we need to show $T$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors instead of $n$ distinct eigenvalues [in order to prove $T$ is diagonalizable],' and he or she is right, because there are no hypotheses on $T$. (Well, technically one could do other things than exhibit $n$ LI eigenvectors, but it would have to be equivalent to it, and not equivalent to $n$ distinct eigenvalues.)

Comment: @whacka I'm sorry, I didn't realise you weren't the author of the first comment in the question. The answer to the question in the aforementioned comment is still no. Given a $n\times n$ matrix $T$ with no other hypothesis, you do not need to find $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors to prove it is diagonalizable.  It's true that it might not have $n$ distinct eigenvalues, but it might also not be diagonalizable.

Comment: May I ask where this question comes from? Exercise 8.A.11 in Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition?  I'm just curious because the third edition was not yet published in 2014 while this exercise wasn't included in the second edition. It's strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generalization of the previous answer:

for every $a$:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&a\\0&1\end{array}\right)^2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&2a\\0&1\end{array}\right).$$

RHS is usually not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 2):

Possible counterexample, there may be a mistake: consider $A:=\displaystyle\left(\begin{array}{cc} i& 1 \\ 0& i  \end{array}\right)$ which is in its Jordan Canonical Form and hence, non-diagonalizable. Notice that $A^2=\displaystyle\left(\begin{array}{cc} -1& 2i \\ 0& -1  \end{array}\right)$ which has Jordan Canonical Form $\displaystyle\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& -1 \\ 0& 1 \end{array}\right)$, which isn't diagonalizable.

Let me know if there is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Consider any non diagonal nilpotent matrix or non diagonal matrix with all the eigen values are same in general.

Comment: You need to assume that the matrix is not a scalar multiple of the identity.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez thanks for the nice point.